# Elasticsearch через некоторое время перестает работать

Tags: elasticsearch

Запускаю сервер, добавляю данные, создаю индексы. Через пару дней **Elasticsearch** перестает находить данные, которые есть.

Переполняется память, из положения выходили очищением папки данные и пересозданием индексов.

Потом нашли, что нужно в настройках увеличить выделяемую под **Elasticsearch** память. Установили переменную окружения export `ES_HEAP_SIZE=10` - все равно не ищет данные.

После перезагрузки севрвера `$ES_HEAP_SIZE` удаляется.

В БД (**mongodb**) ищем данные в определенном поле по некоторому шаблону (*text*).
Первое время находит нужное количество записей, но потом от сервера приходит ответ **200 OK**

```
[
  {
    "err": "No Living connections"
  }
]
```

Что я делаю неправильно? Может быть, вообще причина в другом? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469375/elasticsearch-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5 ?

Comment: Это тот же самый вопрос, просто в том обсуждении я не могу комментировать, отвечать на ваши уточняющие вопросы. Пожалуйста,  отпишите здесь.  

Ответ на вопрос в комментах: В БД (mongodb) ищем данные в определенном поле по некоторому шаблону (text). Первое время находит нужное количество записей, но потом от сервера приходит ответ 200 OK [ { "err": "No Living connections" } ]

Comment: Так надо отредактировать тот вопрос, а не создавать новый. И вроде свои вопросы можно было комментировать, вне зависимости от репутации. Вы же тут отвечаете.

Comment: @Vartlok Я думаю у него что то с аккаунтом, там же создатель другой

Comment: Mike, именно так.